# Find the $x$ intercepts of $x^3+x^2-4x-4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to find the $x$ intercepts of $x^3+x^2-4x-4$.

The solution in my book shows these as: $(2,0)$, $(-2,0)$, $(-1,0)$ whereas I get just $(4, 0)$, $(-1, 0)$.

My working:

$x^3+x^2-4x-4$ =

$x^2(x+1)-4(x+1)$ =

$(x^2-4)(x+1)$

Thus, intercepts when $x$ is equal to $4$ and $-1$.

Where have I gone wrong and how can I arrive at $x$ intercepts of $2, -2$ and $1$?

Comment: You wrote $x^2 - 4$ which needs to be further factorised as $(x + 2)(x - 2)$.

Comment: Oh. Yes I see that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as said in the comments, I will quickly put this into answer form.

The $x^2-4$ can be simplified to $(x+2)(x-2)$, so the roots are $2$, $-2$, and $-1$.

Comment: When finding the roots, is the idea that for any factor, there should be no power. We want to factor out all powers?

Comment: You are correct @DougFir. However, some things cannot be simplified (using real numbers), such as $x^2+x+1$. When this happens, you disregard that part entirely. So for example if you simplified it to $(x^2+x+1)(x+1)$, then your sole root would be $x = -1$.

Comment: Got it, thank you